# $_GET is empty after header() using inside cron task in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, get, header

I'm trying to do a scheduled task which run a php script.
It must do:

1. log the user for a WordPress
2. If it's authenticated -> go to a specific URL with params to import some data
3. Log out the user

I managed to run the task on the server, run the script, authenticate the user but when I run this piece of code:

```
if( authenticate( $user, $password, $email ) ){
    ob_clean();
    /*** REDIRECT TO THE PAGE ***/
    // wp_redirect("https://my-site?post_type=foo&action=do-it");
    header("location: https://my-site?post_type=foo&action=do-it");
    ob_flush();
    wp_logout();
    echo 'yes';
    exit();
} else {
    echo 'no';
    die();
}
```

It manages to go to the right file but `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` are empty... why?

```
public function __construct() {
  if ( !empty($_GET) && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'bateaux' && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'do-it') {
    //that works here if the user is logged in and run in the browser
   add_action( 'admin_init', [ __CLASS__, 'plugin_do_import_data' ] );
 }else{
    // go here when run by the script because $_GET is empty
  }

}
```

I would like to get `$_GET['post_type']` and `$_GET['action']` to scope the treatment.
I need to find a way to can run correctly the WordPress hook by `add_action()` in order to use some function like `get_term_by()` which must run inside  `admin_init` hook.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I suspect there's a missing piece of the puzzle here which we can't see. What happens when you just type `https://my-site?post_type=foo&action=do-it` directly into the browser's address bar? That should be exactly the same as what happens when you redirect to it with a `Location:` header. If it is, then you can ignore all your redirect code for now, and just concentrate on why typing that URL doesn't do what you expect - possibly some server configuration for handling "pretty" URLs accidentally discarding the query string.

Comment: why not replace the header with a curl request? it offloads the need to follow redirects in the *cron*

Comment: @IMSoP Before make this PHP script, I already did the code on Wordpress site logged in with the same user, I tested it again few minutes ago and it works because $_GET is not empty. Run by the scheduled task, thats enter inside the else.... I will add a part of the code.

Comment: Hm, when you say this is a "scheduled task", how is it being run exactly? The `Location:` header is an instruction to the browser to load that URL, but is there actually a browser involved in this case? Also note that the code doesn't run in the order you describe: it logs the user out *and then* redirects them, because PHP will continue executing until the `exit();` before sending the redirect to the browser.

Comment: @IMSoP The scheduled task run a php file with arguments to logged the user.
If the user is logged in ( I based my code on [this link](https://webhostinghero.org/wordpress-authentication-integration-with-php/) )to logged the user without passed by the browser ), I should use the browser url with $_GET params to run an import data.

Comment: If the script is not being run from a browser, the `header()` call will not be having any effect. It doesn't "fetch" or "call" that other URL, it's only effect is to _tell the browser to load that page next_. You probably need to rethink your approach, e.g. calling the functions to do the import directly, rather than trying to load the existing URL.